# Automatically save all responses sent to my browser

Tags: google-chrome, network-traffic

I have set up a server that sends me images when I access a webpage on the server. When I have the developer console for Google chrome open on the network tab, I can see a bunch of responses, including the images with their original names. When I reload the page, the images are loaded "from cache".

I would like to automatically save any objects, with their original names, in a folder.
How can I do this? Is there an extension that will help me achieve this?

I have seen people suggest to just go through the cache to find them, but...that can't be the best way to do it.

Comment: maybe try saving the html page itself, it will include the components in a folder with the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatic I'm afraid but [cacheCopy](http://cachecopy.codeplex.com/) works with several browsers and allows saving of images with a number of naming options.

You would need to run it manually though or run it periodically via the Windows scheduler.

Comment: That tool looks useful. I am particularly interested in preserving the original names that were sent by the server. Looking at the naming options, it seems like most of them are just patterns. Presumably, the original names are not stored in cache, so it's not available.

Comment: Not sure I'm afraid, I don't use Chrome much. However, the tool is free so I'd suggest giving it a go.